# webhosting with IP access

Tags: shared-hosting, ip-address, web-hosting

I'm using a shared webhosting service but I can't access my website using http://ip.ad.dre.sse of the website, I have activated a dedicated IP service but the problem has not been solved. What do you suggest to solve this problem?

I need to have IP based access because I'm using a GPS that could be configured only by the server IP (not URL). Any advice will be very helpful.

** edit **

Thanks a lot for your answers, my hosting provider has solved the problem of ip based access. Regarding the dedicated ip service - it is not free, it costs 5 euros, and it could be activated with free account.

Comment: Who is your hosting provider and what hosting plan do you have?

Comment: I'm using the webhosting provider https://www.alwaysdata.com/ , I'm subscribing to the free plan. If you know any webhosting service which allows ip based access, would you advice me?

Comment: Wouldn't you need a dedicated server? A shared host which puts many sites on the same machine is not going to give you access by IP address alone (likely you can get it with /~username on the end, but that sounds like its of no help either).

Comment: It seems unlikely that a webhost would offer free hosting with a dedicated IP address. Are you sure that you have a dedicated IP?

Comment: @Codecraft: You don't need a dedicated server for a dedicated IP. You can get a dedicated IP with VPS or shared hosting (otherwise shared hosting users wouldn't be able to get SSL certificates). On shared hosting. A single server can have multiple NICs, and you can bind a single NIC to multiple IP addresses as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use dedicated IP address on shared hosting you must have a convincing reason such as using SSL certificated ..., then if you provider accept your condition *maybe* by extra cost you can use a dedicated IP address and then you can use it.

if your application and your hosting provider accept you may using shared IP on a dedicated port ( server-ip-address:888 or any other)

but the best choose is using a VPS service which you have root access and dedicated IP

Comment: Any decent webhost would offer dedicated IPs to their shared hosting users without requiring special permission or explanation. Most web hosts simply include it in their control panel as an add-on feature that you can purchase and be automatically activated without any manual intervention or authorization from the web host. It's required to enable TLS/SSL and HTTPS, which is a common enough requirement to make dedicated IPs on shared hosting a standard offering.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure they give you FREE static IP? I believe they dont. At paid shared hosting, you have to purchase addon static IP. If you dont want to purchase static IP, yaaa, you use shared IP. Please kindly check it once again with your hosting provider. :)

Comment: yeah , Static IP is NOT FREE , like you have explained it could be purchased like an addon. :)

Comment: Wow.... quite expensive as well. :) But you only purchase static IP, right? There is no other fee, right? If so, it is OK. Because with my hosting provider, I only need to pay 3 euros/month. :)